# removing dates from generate_Series in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

im trying to remove some dates from generate_Series in postgres liie this:-

```
select min(dt)+'1 day' from generate_series(date_trunc('day',now()) , date_trunc('day',now()+'30 day'),'1 day') as s(dt)
except
SELECT dt
FROM generate_series(date_trunc('day',ca."startAt"), date_trunc('day',ca."startAt"), '1 day') as ex1(dt))
```

but seems like min()+1day is always the same value no matter what startAt is

Comment: I removed the unrelated tags from your post (if this was incorrect, feel free to update accordingly). Also please tag which version of PostgreSQL you're asking about.

Comment: im using postgres 12.3

Comment: That's not a complete query you have given us.

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate the `EXCEPT` in a subquery, before you aggregate:

```
SELECT min(dt) + '1 day'
FROM (SELECT dt
      FROM generate_series(
              date_trunc('day',now()),
              date_trunc('day',now()+'30 day'),
              '1 day') AS s(dt)
      EXCEPT
      SELECT dt
      FROM generate_series(
              date_trunc('day',ca."startAt"),
              date_trunc('day',ca."startAt"),
              '1 day') AS ex1(dt)
     ) AS q;
```

Comment: I agree. In the original snippet, the `min(dt)` would be applied to `s(dt)` only and not the whole `s(dt) except ex1(dt)`. Still though, this cannot be the full query as the `ca."startAT"` would throw error. The snippet is part of a bigger query.